# APACITE Citation undefined

Tags: texstudio

I'm a beginner to LaTeX and using Texstudio. I need to reference in APA style and seem to have configured my file to use Jabref correctly. However, I'm getting lots of yellow warnings

> citation ** undefined.

The citations appear to be loaded correctly in Jabref. Here is my code. I have not installed any `apacite.sty` files manually. Do I need to do this? Sorry, I've read but am confused by the CTAN document. Many thanks.

```
\usepackage{apacite}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\label{Bibliography}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"
```

Edit: I should add about 70% of my references do work.

Edit 2:

This is my class.I don't load any packages relating to the Bibliography to my knowledge.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
```

These links work correctly:

```
\cite{aveyard2014doing}
@Book{aveyard2014doing,
Title                    = {Doing a Literature Review in Health and Social Care},
  Author                   = {Aveyard, Helen},
  Publisher                = {McGraw-Hill Education (UK)},
  Year                     = {2014}
 }

\cite{bridgstock2009graduate}

@Article{bridgstock2009graduate,
 Title                    = {The graduate attributes we’ve overlooked:       
Enhancing graduate employability through career management skills},
Author                   = {Bridgstock, Ruth},
Journal                  = {Higher Education Research \& Development},
Year                     = {2009},
Number                   = {1},
Pages                    = {31--44},
Volume                   = {28},
Publisher                = {Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

And then, not working:

```
\citeA{knight2002employability}

@Article{knight2002employability,
Title                    = {Employability through the curriculum},
Author                   = {Knight, Peter and Yorke, Mantz},
Journal                  = {Tertiary Education and Management},
Year                     = {2002},
Number                   = {4},
Pages                    = {261-276},
Volume                   = {8},
Publisher                = {Springer}
}


\cite{tomlinson2010investing}
@Article{tomlinson2010investing,
 Title                    = {Investing in the self: structure, agency and    identity in graduates' employability},
 Author                   = {Tomlinson, Michael},
 Journal                  = {Education, Knowledge \& Economy},
 Year                     = {2010},
 Number                   = {2},
 Pages                    = {73--88},
 Volume                   = {4},

 Publisher                = {Taylor \& Francis}
 }
```

Comment: Please do not use this buggy template.